# Regions bounded by $n$ line segments

Tags: geometry

> What is the maximum number of bounded regions you can make in a plane using $n$ line segments without lifting the pencil? The picture below shows regions bounded by $3$, $4$, and $5$ line segments. 
>   [image]

Comment: I can't open the picture. Do you have a guess for the answer? If yes, try induction.

Comment: Could you show the diagrams for $6$,$7$ and $8$ line segments if possible? Also, [Here](http://thoughtsongiftededucation.blogspot.com/2009/09/using-graph-theory-with-young-kids.html) we learn that, _"...ever heard about the traveling salesman problem? The problem aims to find the shortest tour of a group of cities without repetition. Clearly, this is equivalent to draw the star without lifting the pencil or going over the same line twice."_